# About Istanbul Transit Visa

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, isl, mumbai

I am Indian Citizen. I having Valid Malta Visa. Now My flight is from India to Istanbul and from Istanbul to Malta. I having Halt in Istanbul for around 3-4 Hours. So please let me know can I have to obtain Transit Visa for Istanbul

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will need a transit visa as long as you are not leaving the airport. I have been through IST 3 times and I never required a visa. You can find more info [here](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/frequently-asked-questions.en.mfa)